# Multistage amplifier with frequency response

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

[image]I am having a problem to analyze this amplifier all in one, I need a way to get into this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just need a hint to get a way into this.

Comment: You must add a little bit of your throghtprocess/effort. Otherwise it'll be closed as off topic.

Comment: Help us to help you, show us where you are so far, then we can contribute answers at your level. For instance, what's the configuration of Q1+Q2 called, and why? What do Q4 and Q3 do? What's Q6's configuration called, what is it doing, how does it help you meet the output resistance specification? What's Q5 doing, why does it need Q6 there? This amplifier can be broken down into individual sections, with a limited amount of interaction between them. Designing a whole amplifier means designing each section, while allowing for the limited interaction.

Comment: I know that Vc2 = 5 Volts which lead us that VE5 = 5.7 volts and that all I could get to see at this moment, So any hint matters